# SQL - select actual data for current year and plan data for future year

Tags: sql

Column A = Year
Column B = type

I want to select 2019 with Actual (type) and 2020,2021,2022 with Plan (type)

I know this can be solved using concat+where clause but I am trying to see if there is a better solution?

```
SELECT year,
                  CASE 
                  WHEN year in ('2017','2018','2019') THEN type in ('Actual')
                  ELSE type in ('plan')
                  END AS S
               
from table
```

- but this does not give the desired result.Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where (year = '2019' and type = 'Actual') or
      (year in ('2020', '2021', '2022') and type = 'Plan')
```